# Solve extremely simple equation in prolog: A = B + C?

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming

I have an extremely simple equation that I would like to be able to solve in prolog:

A = B + C

I'd like to be able to write a predicate expressing this relation, that can handle any one of the arguments not being instantiated. There is no need to generalize to more complex relations or equations.

```
myEquation(A, B, C) :-
...something...
```

That I could call with the following semantics:

```
myEquation(A,1,2).
>    A = 3.
myEquation(3,B,2).
>    B = 1.
myEquation(3,1,C).
>    C = 2.
```

Any ideas? Working with arithmetic operators yields a lot of "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated" errors. It looks like solving arbitrary systems of equations is beyond the scope of most prolog implementations, but I'm hoping that this extremely simple equation is tractable.

Comment: It's not beyond the scope of most Prolog implementations. You just have to do a little reading. ;) Have you looked at the CLP (constraint logic programming) library?

Comment: see [plus](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=plus/3)/3

Comment: Thank you lurker and CapelliC. I'm working in a very small golang prolog envirionment, and the CLP library is a bit heavy weight (although awesome! thanks for the pointer). Looking at plus/3's implementation has me off to the races.

Comment: You could also write your predicate "long hand" (without `plus/3`) by checking the given variables. For example, `integer(A)` will be true if `A` is an integer. It will just take a few clauses, or an if-then-else construct, to check each case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not particularly fancy, but here it is. If you're not an absolute beginner, you could have done this too:

```
myEquation(A, B, C):- 
    var(A),number(B),number(C) -> A is B+C;
    var(B),number(A),number(C) -> B is A-C;
    var(C),number(A),number(B) -> C is A-B;
    A =:= B + C.
```

update: 
The same with Constraint Logic Programming:

```
:- use_module(library(clpq)).

myEquation(A, B, C):-
    {A = B + C}.
```

Comment: Your first version is incorrect. `myEquation(0,0,0)` should succeed (reliable sources tell me), but your version fails. Testing for `var(A)` etc. is mostly error prone. Instead, test only for `nonvar(X)` and use an unchecked `(is)/2` as the last case.

Comment: @zslevi: Please remove the incorrect version so that we can upvote your correct solution with constraints!

Comment: @false : fixed it now. I don't see the issue with var vs nonvar though.

Comment: Your current solution is somewhat possible too, but quite an extra effort. Also, you have a lot of asymmetry: `myEquation(A,0+0,0)` produces an instantiation error - it should either succeed, or produce rather a type error.

Answer (score 3):

If your domain is integers, **use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!**

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

:- assert(clpfd:full_answer).       % for SICStus Prolog

myEquation(A,B,C) :-
   A #= B+C.
```

Some sample queries with [sicstus-prolog](/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog), version 4.3.2:

```
?- myEquation(A,B,C).
B+C#=A, A in inf..sup, B in inf..sup, C in inf..sup ? ;
no

?- myEquation(A,2,C).
2+C#=A, A in inf..sup, C in inf..sup ? ;
no    

?- myEquation(X,X,X).
X+X#=X, X in inf..sup ? ;
no
```

Let's run the same queries with [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog), version 7.3.3:

```
?- myEquation(A,B,C).
B+C#=A.

?- myEquation(A,2,C).
2+C#=A.

?- myEquation(X,X,X).
X = 0.                              % succeeds deterministically
```