# prolog code in python with pyswip not working

Tags: python, prolog, swi-prolog

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369666/solve-extremely-simple-equation-in-prolog-a-b-c).

I want following prolog code to be embedded in a python program:

```
myEquation(A, B, C):- 
    var(A),number(B),number(C) -> A is B+C;
    var(B),number(A),number(C) -> B is A-C;
    var(C),number(A),number(B) -> C is A-B;
    A =:= B + C.
```

I installed `pyswip` package and tried following code:

```
from pyswip import Prolog
prolog = Prolog()
prolog.assertz("myEquation(A, B, C):- var(A),number(B),number(C) -> A is B+C; var(B),number(A),number(C) -> B is A-C; var(C),number(A),number(B) -> C is A-B; A =:= B + C.")
prolog.assertz("myEquation(3,1,C).")
```

But it gives me error:

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator priority clash
ERROR: assertz((myEquation(A, B, C):- var(A),number(B),number(C) -> A is B+C; var(B),number(A),number(C) -> B is A-C; var(C),number(A),number(B) -> C is A-B; A
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  =:= B + C.)). 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prologpy.py", line 4, in <module>
    prolog.assertz("myEquation(A, B, C):- var(A),number(B),number(C) -> A is B+C; var(B),number(A),number(C) -> B is A-C; var(C),number(A),number(B) -> C is A-B; A =:= B + C.")
  File "/home/cardio/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyswip/prolog.py", line 140, in assertz
    next(cls.query(assertion.join(["assertz((", "))."]), catcherrors=catcherrors))
  File "/home/cardio/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyswip/prolog.py", line 127, in __call__
    "Returned: '", str(term), "'."]))
pyswip.prolog.PrologError: Caused by: 'assertz((myEquation(A, B, C):- var(A),number(B),number(C) -> A is B+C; var(B),number(A),number(C) -> B is A-C; var(C),number(A),number(B) -> C is A-B; A =:= B + C.)).'. Returned: 'error(syntax_error(operator_clash), string(b'assertz((myEquation(A, B, C):- var(A),number(B),number(C) -> A is B+C; var(B),number(A),number(C) -> B is A-C; var(C),number(A),number(B) -> C is A-B; A =:= B + C.)). ', 152))'.
```

How can I solve this problem. I can use some other prolog-related python package also as are [listed here](https://pypi.org/search/?q=prolog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` at the end of the predicate definition is too much. Get rid of it.

For example, this is correct:

```
?- assertz((foo :- bar)).
```

but this is not correct:

```
?- assertz((foo :- bar.)).
```

If you read the examples [provided with pyswip](https://pypi.org/project/pyswip/) you should notice that the above native Prolog code translates to:

```py
from pyswip import Prolog
prolog = Prolog()
prolog.assertz("(foo :- bar)")
```

and **not** as you have written,

```py
prolog.assertz("(foo :- bar.)")
```

Comment: Yes, the program runs with this. But there is no output. I tried `res = prolog.assertz("myEquation(3,1,C)")` but `res` is `None`. How to get result of last prolog statement?

Comment: @rnso Maybe you should read the documentation of pyswip more carefully. And I don't know how I feel about answering new questions in the comments under the answer to your original question. Normally you'd just ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: @rnso I have absolutely no idea what you mean by "more upvotes are expected". You got an answer to your question; you now seem to have another question. I am not going to play this game of hiding questions and answers in comments.